# pandas - add new computed columns with for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a data frame with many columns that I need to divide by a column to compute proportions. Can someone help with a for loop for this? In the given data example below I want to add columns `c1p = c1/ct, c2p=c2/ct, c3p=c3/ct, c4p=c4/ct`.

```
id   c1   c2   c3   c4   ct
1    6    8    8    12    34
2    5    3    11   6     25 
3    3    9    6    12    30
4    14   10   10   3     37
```

Comment: Why would you want a `for` loop for this? Just reference the dataframe columns and divide through to get a vectorized approach. That pushes the calculation down into numpy and will probably be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: I am pretty new to programming, can you please give an example of how to do that with above example data? I need to do it for 80 columns so did not want to create individual columns.

Answer (score 0):

The power of DataFrames is that you can do stuff column by column. Like this:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    df[f'c{i}p'] = df[f'[c{i}'] / df['ct']
```

Comment: Thank you for this Steve, my actual data does not have names as c{i}. is there a way to use column index or something else. I need to do it for 80 columns so did not want to create individual columns.

Comment: @PushprajVerma If you can come up with a pattern that matches all the names, then you can cycle through the df.columns and only do the division on columns that match that pattern. Let me know if I can help you do this =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized approach to get another dataframe `df_p` which contains all the per-unit values you need:

```
df_p = df.filter(regex='c[0-9]').divide(df['ct'], axis=0)
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. ,my actual column names are not c1, c2... (they are random business names). thanks

Comment: @pushpraj-verma Ok.  Please provide more information, i.e., the column names, for more help.